# Zend SQL - conditional where clause

Tags: php, mysql, sql, zend-framework

I have the following Zend SQL query:

```
$select = $this->select()
->where($this->_quote('VerDate <= ?', $todate))
->where($this->_quote('VerFieldId = ?', $fieldid));
if (count($records) > 0) {
    $this->select()->where($this->_quote('VerRecordId IN (?)', $records));
}
$this->select()->group('VerRecordId');
```

I only want to add the where condition on VerRecordId if an array of $records has been passed to the function.

When I run the query at the moment it stops after the where clause on VerFieldId.

Can anyone help with what I need to do to amend the query?

UPDATE:

I have solved the issue using the following code. However, if anyone knows if this can be structured better, please let me know.

```
$where = array();
$where['VerDate <= ?'] = $todate;
$where['VerFieldId = ?'] = $fieldid;
if (count($records) > 0) {
    $where['VerRecordId IN (?)'] = $records;
}
$select = $this->select();
$this->_where($select,$where);
$select->group('VerRecordId');
```

This allowed me to conditionally add in the VerRecordId condition.

Answer (score 1):

> ZF2

```
 $sql = new Sql($this->adapter);
          $select = new Select($this->table);
          $where = new  \Zend\Db\Sql\Where();
          $where->equalTo('field1',(string) $value1);
          $where->greaterThan('field2','value2') ;
          $where->equalTo('field3','value3');
          $select->where($where);
          $statement = $sql->prepareStatementForSqlObject($select);
          $result = $statement->execute();
```

> ZF1

```
$select = $this->select();      
$select->setIntegrityCheck(false) // if you have joins
            ->from(array('tablename' => 'tablename',))
            $select->where('field = ?', $value);
$select->where(new Zend_Db_Expr("field <> 'value'"));   
        $result = $this->fetchAll($select);
```

and then you can loop the $result

i hope it helps you

http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.db.sql.html

Comment: Hi Amarjit, thanks for your reply. I forgot to mention that I am using Zend Framework version 1.11.11, in which I'm not sure you can use the notation you describe above?

Comment: i have added for zf1 as well